# Laravel Validation: soft delete + unique email + update

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-7

I'm trying to set up a client registration check and profile edit.

1. I'm using soft delete
2. E-mail has to be unique (not counting the delted ones of course)
3. If profile is edited (id is present) it has to ignore that fields email

So far I have

```
'email' => [
    'required',
    'email',
    'unique:clients,email,NULL,deleted_at,deleted_at,NULL',
],
```

Now this works correctly and detects the unique emails that are not deleted, but it gives me errors when I need to edit the profile off the client. I tried adding additional unique settings, but they seem to be getting ignored:

```
'email' => [
    'required',
    'email',
    'unique:clients,email,NULL,deleted_at,deleted_at,NULL',
    Rule::unique('clients')->ignore('id', (int)$request->input('id')) // <- from Laravel docs, but is not working
],
```

I found solutions with only one of these requirements, but I can't seem to combine them.

Edit: The fix was

```
'email'=>['required','email',Rule::unique('clients','email')->ignore($request->input('id'))->whereNull('deleted_at')],
```

Comment: Try Following Code
`
 $this->validate($request,[
      'email'=>['required','email',Rule::unique('clients',’email’)->ignore(auth()->id()->whereNull('deleted_at'))]
              ]); 
 `

Comment: @kunalrajput I get `Call to a member function whereNull() on integer`

Comment: is your client authenticated user

Comment: Nah, you just had a mistake in closing ")" and I don't need the auth id, but the request id. Fixed it now, thanks to you. Add it as answer and Ill approve

Comment: sure, yeah it was a typo .thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 $this->validate($request,[
            'email'=>['required','email',Rule::unique('clients','email')->ignore($id)->whereNull('deleted_at')]
        ]);
```